# Two tests dependent on same test

Tags: automation, testng

I have two tests that are dependent on same test(Using DependsON). Are these dependent test cases will be executed one after other?

I am using testNG version-6.10

Answer (score 1):

Would the dependent testcases run one after the other or together depends on what your parallel execution strategy is.

- If you have set `parallel='methods'` in your suite file, then both the dependent methods will run together.
- If you have disabled parallel execution (by setting `parallel=false` in your suite file), then the dependent methods will run one after the other. Which runs first and which runs next is not determined (since TestNG relies on reflection to query methods from a class)

But in either cases, they will be executed only after the master test (the one on which both your tests depend on) runs successfully.